# Change "I had a car" to passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> Change the voice from active to passive of the following sentence:
>   **I had a car.**

The active sentence is "I had a car". In passive form is it "a car had had been by me" or some other answer? I found this question online on a page for competitive exams.

Comment: No passive form. I think it gas no passive form

Answer (score 9):

The consensus from the comments is that

1. The passive of this sentence would be "A car was had by me", *BUT*
2. this is not idiomatic English: *HAVE*, in the sense of *possess*, is not ordinarily employed in the passive voice.

Comment: This is so, but I might point out that "had" in the sense of "fooled", which is slightly slang, is generally in the passive voice.  "You've been had" means that you've been fooled or "taken" or "conned."  Edit: I see Fumblefingers has pointed out this usage also, but I think of this as slang.  I can't think of another example of passive voice of have that is common.

Comment: @BobRodes Good point; I wrote too quickly in the effort to get this off the Unanswered list. Fixed now.

Comment: *A car was possessed by me* or *A car was owned by me* would work a little better, but still sounds at least a bit awkward in normal speech/writing.

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct answer would be:

> A car had been had by me.

Because the finite form of the verb is changed (to be + past participle).

Comment: Since the original is simple past (*had* and not *had had*), *a car was had by me* would fit better, though this would still be quite an unusual thing to say.

Comment: @choster Maybe you are right. But yeah still, unusual !!!

Answer (score -1):

> I had a car

is active voice

> A car was owned by me
>   A car was possessed by me

would be acceptable passive voice

Comment: But those are the passive voice equivalents of "I owned a car" and "I possessed a car" respectively. Neither one is "I had a car" in passive voice.

Answer (score -3):

> I was found/seen to have a car.

or

> a car was owned by me

or

> it was found that I had a car.

Comment: You should probably correct the typos in these examples.

Comment: Welcome to ELL :-). This is a website about language, so correct spelling and grammar are important. The help centre specifies that you ought to [write to the best of your ability](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Aside from that it is always good to explain your answer a bit, not just give solutions: this would help both the OP and the future users of the website to solve similar problems on their own. Thanks!

Comment: The third one is not even passive voice.